# Django exception on server start up - module not found

Tags: python, django, server

I have searched online for other solutions with little luck. Posting here is a last resort.

Everything was working well with my Django project. Then suddenly it stopped running the server as it used to. I'm not sure at all what I have done wrong.

The issue is persistent across all of the git branches (it wasn't like this before) - making it even more confusing as the problem is not isolated to my branch only.

Here is the error traceback:

```
    WARNINGS:
?: (1_7.W001) MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES is not set.
    HINT: Django 1.7 changed the global defaults for the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware, django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware, and django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware were removed from the defaults. If your project needs these middleware then you should configure this setting.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000001A7227EB598>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\5CCS2SEG_Major\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\5CCS2SEG_Major\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\5CCS2SEG_Major\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 168, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\5CCS2SEG_Major\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\5CCS2SEG_Major\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\5CCS2SEG_Major\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 185, in build_graph
    self.load_disk()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\5CCS2SEG_Major\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 103, in load_disk
    migration_module = import_module("%s.%s" % (module_name, migration_name))
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\5CCS2SEG_Major\venv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\5CCS2SEG_Major\connect_therapy\migrations\0021_auto_20180313_1946.py", line 4, in <module>
    import django.contrib.auth.base_user
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.auth.base_user'
```

Also, note that I tried changing to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES [...] in settings.py - but it didnt help.

Here is settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.7.
For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/
For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'key'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True # should be true unless doing test on local network

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] # should be [] unless doing test on local network (then it should be ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'co.apps.CTherapyConfig',
    "sslserver", 
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# This must be changed for production
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER = '+number'

TWILIO_ACC_SID = 'key'

TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = 'token'


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Any ideas/suggestions are welcome.

Just to reiterate. This came out of the blue. No idea what caused it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'solution' at the end was to just make a new virtual environment. For some reason the old one messed up.

Answer (score 0):

It came out because something changed in your project and a migration now fails.

In the error log you can see

```
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\5CCS2SEG_Major\connect_therapy\migrations\0021_auto_20180313_1946.py", line 4, in <module>
    import django.contrib.auth.base_user
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.auth.base_user'
```

What that migration does? Is still valid or the project is changed and the migration try to load resources that are not anymore available?

If you run `python manage.py shell` are you able to import from 'django.contrib.auth.base_user'? The problem seems to be in that migration